# Navbar menu contents overflowing outside of the parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the navbar menu to appear in the 'header-container' menu, but for some reason, the navbar links flow outside (before revising browser window). I cannot figure out why but I suspect it has something to do with this line:

div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse"

Whenever I add a float left to the navHeaderCollapse the links inside. Adding an overflow: none; just hides the overflow but there shouldn't be any overflow in the first place.

Why are the links not staying inside the header-container div?

```css
#header-container{
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ff0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- STYLESHEETS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>




<header id="header-container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>

                    <!-- MOBILE BUTTON - VIEWABLE ON MOBILE SIZED BROWSERS ONLY -->
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                        <!-- HAMBURGER MENU -->
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: please view full page from the demo to see the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just erase the fixed `width: 960px;` from your `#header-container` CSS rule

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjVjqE

Comment: but I want the width to be 960px

Comment: Then apply those 960px width to the `container` class

Comment: thanks, turns out I just needed to set a max-width to that container and is a much simpler solution!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're adding a fixed width to a an element that contains the Bootstrap header. When `.navbar-right` (defined by Bootstrap) tries to `float` to the `right`, it breaks the layout unless the parent has a width of `100%` (the default). Simply remove your `width` specification on `#header-container` and your links will correctly sit within your header:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- STYLESHEETS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<header id="header-container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>
        <!-- MOBILE BUTTON - VIEWABLE ON MOBILE SIZED BROWSERS ONLY -->
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
          <!-- HAMBURGER MENU -->
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

### **EDIT**

In order to have the navbar occupy a maximum width of `960px`, you're looking to modify the predefined `.container` class, rather than creating a brand new one. Note that `navbar-static-top` **forces** you to have a full-width (as it's static), so you'll also need to remove that.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- STYLESHEETS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<header id="header-container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>
        <!-- MOBILE BUTTON - VIEWABLE ON MOBILE SIZED BROWSERS ONLY -->
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
          <!-- HAMBURGER MENU -->
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: true but I want the width, which is why I made the div!

Comment: When you say you want to specify a custom `width` for a Bootstrap navbar, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Typically the Bootstrap navbar occupies the full width, and you create your containers **within** it. Do you want the Bootstrap navbar to be centralised, with a different (perhaps recoloured) navbar on the left and right? You would create a second navbar **inside** of the Bootstrap navbar, rather than creating a container for it. Or perhaps that the links on the right have  a greater indentation? You would do that with `margin-right`.

Comment: maybe I have approached this the wrong way. I want to have the maximum width of the navbar to be 960px wide (so that all the content is inside of a container 960px wide )

Comment: turns out I went about this the wrong way and was a simple fix by setting a max-width to the inner container :)

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, you are adding `.container` div inside your structure. It inherits rules from bootstrap and breaks your layout.

```
<header id="header-container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container"> <!-- remove this element, or change name-->
                <div class="navbar-header">
```